# TypeScript async await does not always seem to wait ("block and come back")

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, async-await

I am starting to use the `async await` pattern more over the standard Promise syntax, as it can keep the code flatter. I have played and experimented with them a bit and **thought** I understood how to use them.

That has now come crumbling down!

I have a function that returns a Promise...

```
private async checkSecurityTokenForNearExpiry(): Promise<boolean> {
        const expiryOffset = 10;
        try {      
          let existingToken = await this.userAuthorisationService.getSecurityToken();
          if (existingToken != null && !existingToken.isTokenExpired(expiryOffset)) {
            return true;
          }

          // Attempt to get a new token. 
          this.logger.debug('checkSecurityTokenForNearExpiry requesting new token.');
          this.getSecurityTokenWithRefreshToken().subscribe(obs => {
            return true;
          },
          error => {
            // All errors already logged
            return false;
          });
        } catch (error) {
          this.logger.error(`checkSecurityToken ${error}`);
          return false;
        }
      }
```

This happens to call other function that returns a promise and also has on Observable, but all this seems to be ok.

I then call this function as follows...

```
this.getDataStoreValues().then(async () => {

      await this.checkSecurityTokenForNearExpiry(); // <-- not waiting

      requestData();  // <-- this is called before checkSecurityTokenForNearExpiry returns
      ...
```

This is inside another Promise `then` callback marked as `async`, (which should be ok?), but to my alarm the call to `this.checkSecurityTokenForNearExpiry()` is not finished before I see the `requestData()` being called. I don't need the `boolean` result of `checkSecurityTokenForNearExpiry` but added this just to see if returning something would make s difference, but it didn't.

I am lost here!

Does anyone know what I am missing here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`async`/`await` are working as expected but there are two factors that prevent your code from working correctly.

1. Observables have no special interaction with `async` functions. This means that they are fire and forget just as they are in normal functions. You are not awaiting `getSecurityTokenWithRefreshToken` but even if you did `await` it, it would still not behave as you want because the result would actually be the subscription returned by the call to `subscribe` wrapped in a `Promise`.
2. The callbacks taken as arguments by `subscribe` are not intended to return values so returning from them has no effect as `Observable` implementations will not propagate their results.

In order to make this work you need to convert the `Observable` into a `Promise` as follows

```
async checkSecurityTokenForNearExpiry(): Promise<boolean> {
    const expiryOffset = 10;
    try {
        let existingToken = await this.userAuthorisationService().getSecurityToken();
        if (existingToken != null && !existingToken.isTokenExpired(expiryOffset)) {
            return true;
        }
        // Attempt to get a new token. 
        this.logger.debug('checkSecurityTokenForNearExpiry requesting new token.');
        try {
            await this.getSecurityTokenWithRefreshToken().toPromise();
            return true;
        } catch (error) {
            return false;
        }
    } catch (error) {
        this.logger.error(`checkSecurityToken ${error}`);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Note, if you are using RxJS you may need to add the following import

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
```

Comment: thanks for that indepth explanation! So it was the Observable that was the problem. The `toPromise()` fixes it, and saves me having to wrap it in a Promise and manually `resolving` (and I need to make sure I call `complete()` on the observable in `getSecurityTokenWithRefreshToken()` otherwise it does not return, which I had missed as well). Another one for me to watch out for.

Comment: Interesting remark about `complete`, I hadn't considered that either